Need suggestion to implement restrictive permissions to Kusto Tables and Functions
I would like to restrict viewer permissions of a specific Security Group to all database objects except few functions. In other words, the members of that one security Group should be only able to see\execute 10 functions. Should not be able to directly query the table(s) schema.
Scenario Prototype Steps:
I tried Restricted view access policy option.

I created a table Table1. Assigned Restricted view access policy to
the table Table1. I created a function fnGetTable1. Gave my PME
Account Database UnrestrictedViewer permission at database level.
My Corp account has only database viewer permissions.  My Corp
account is not able to execute the function fnGetTable1.

My ask is, my Corp account should be able to execute the function fnGetTable1 but not directly query the table Table1. Is this possible?

Not a perfect solution, but possibly a workaround ? you might set up row level security on the table to limit the table output for certain users. As a result, restricted users would see table, but they would not see any data inside.
